# Django translation: pick variables

Tags: django, localization, internationalization, translation

We're building a project, where we need to translate notifications into different languages.

The problem is that, unlike standard `"Hello, %(first_name)s"`, we need to have `"Halo, Herr %(last_name)s"` depending on the language.

Another words, the variables we want to use in the translated block depend on the language.

What would be the best way to implement it? I would really like to avoid having to implement different templates for every language..

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having:

```
user_data = {
    'first_name': 'Charlie', 
    'last_name': 'Brown',
}
```

1.

Compiling `_('Hello, %(first_name)s') % user_data`, while supplying the translation `Halo, Herr %(last_name)s` results in a `a format specification for argument 'first_name' doesn't exist in 'msgstr'` error, **however** the mo file is created, and the translation works ok! (Tested with gettext 0.18.1 running under windows).

2.

You can use python newer string formatting: `_('Hello, {first_name}').format(**user_data)`, and translate into `Halo, Her, {last_name}`

3.
Hackish:

```
_("Hello %s") % (user_data[_('hello_name_field')])

#or uglier but safe:
_("Hello %s") % (user_data.get(_('hello_name_field'), user_data['first_name'])
```